# Set canvas origin to the lower-left corner

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to set the origin to lower-left of the canvas? I tried scaling by −1 but after that everything is upside down. I need to make something like a coordinate system but only with the positive part (first quadrant). So I need it to start with 0.0 at down-left corner.

Answer (score 26):

```
ctx.translate(0, canvas.height);
ctx.scale(1, -1);
```

**[See a demo on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/w6rx3/)**

Comment: But the text is upside down :(

Comment: @user986871: Then do `ctx.scale(1, -1)` once before and after every time you draw text.

Comment: @icktoofay I tried what you suggested in your comment but it didnt work, the text just disapeared, like pushed off screen

Comment: @MisterSirCode You also have to do ctx.translate(0, 0); before, and ctx.translate(0, canvas.height); after

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way to set the origin to lower-left of the canvas?

Not quite the way you'd like, no. The best you can do there is what icktoofay said.

That being said it isn't too hard to make a function to convert between one system and the other. For example:

```
// Given an X,Y in 1st quadrant cartesian coordinates give the corresponding screen coordinate
function cartToScreen(px, py) {
  return [px, -py + HEIGHT];
};
```

So you'd write:

```
var coords = cartToScreen(50,50);
// draws 50 pixels from the bottoom instead of 50 pixels from the top
ctx.fillText("lalala", coords[0], coords[1]);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ctbzX/)

In any case, I'd strongly suggest that if you are at all able to just get used to screen coordinates. It will save you from loads of headaches in the future if you don't always have to account for this little difference.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest and correct ways is to use ctx.transform() method [documentation is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform)

Comment: But not if you don't want text to not flip (which is usually the case)

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to "overload" the entire Canvas API itself (and then typically you start with only the functions you need) such that when you use any `x,y` value, it sends that on as `x, canvas.height - y`. That way we don't need "new" functions, we can just keeping using the ones we're already used to, they'll just draw using "natural" coordinates rather than standard graphics coordinates:

```js
/**
 * Look ma: natural coordinate system!
 */

const ctx = getNaturalContext2D(canvas);

ctx.strokeStyle = `black`;
ctx.fillStyle = `red`;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);  // this is near the lower left, now
ctx.lineTo(10, 150);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(200, 200, 0, 0, 180, 10);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font = `bold 30px serif`;
ctx.fillStyle = `black`;
ctx.fillText(`nice`, 120, 120); // and this is near the upper right.

/**
 * Which we achieve by proxying all the canvas
 * functions we need and/or care about:
 */
function getNaturalContext2D(canvas) {
  const _ctx = canvas.getContext(`2d`);

  // All the functions that need y-coord rewrites:
  const contextProxy = {
    moveTo(x, y) {
      _ctx.moveTo(x, canvas.height - y);
    },
    lineTo(x, y) {
      _ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height - y);
    },
    lineTo(x, y) {
      _ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height - y);
    },
    bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, x, y) {
      const h = canvas.height;
      _ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, h - cp1y, cp2x, h - cp2y, x, h - y);
    },
    fillText(text, x, y, maxWidth) {
      _ctx.fillText(text, x, canvas.height - y, maxWidth);
    },
  };

  // Proxies for all the functions we care about that don't need rewrites
  [`beginPath`, `stroke`, `fill`].forEach(
    (fname) =>
      (contextProxy[fname] = function (...args) {
        return _ctx[fname](...args);
      })
  );

  // And proxies for all the context properties we care about.
  [`strokeStyle`, `fillStyle`, `font`].forEach((propname) =>
    Object.defineProperty(contextProxy, propname, {
      get: () => _ctx[propname],
      set: (v) => (_ctx[propname] = v),
    })
  );

  return contextProxy;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="170"></canvas>
```

(And yes: this will technically be a performance hit, but one you're almost certainly never going to notice, since we're effectively just running call forwards)