# How to fix the Mouse Event after change the axis to lower left in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I had change the axis on the html canvas by doing

```
context.translate(0, canvas.height);
context.scale(1,-1);
```

so the canvas will go upside down and the problem now is the mouse event are not match when I want to draw a rectangle.It like when i put the mouse to draw in the bottom of the canvas the rectangle will appear on the top

Can anyone please help me.
Please give me some guidance or references

and I use this link for my reference

[Set canvas origin to the lower-left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707286/set-canvas-origin-to-the-lower-left-corner)

and here the snippet code :

```js
   var ColorCanvas = document.getElementById('ColorCanvas');
        var ctx1 = ColorCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var TransCanvas = document.getElementById('TransCanvas');
        var ctx2 = TransCanvas.getContext('2d');
    
        var rect = {},
            drag = false;


        var bg = new Image();
        bg.src = "Jellyfish.jpg";

        bg.onload = function () {
            ctx1.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
        }

        var annotation = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            w: 0,
            h: 0,
            a: this.x,
            printCoordinates: function () {
                console.log(`X: ${this.x}px, Y: ${this.y}px, Width: ${this.w}px, Height: ${this.h}px`);   
            }     
        };


        //the array of all rectangles
        var boundingBoxes = [];
        // the actual rectangle, the one that is being drawn
        var o = {};
        
        // a variable to store the mouse position
        var m = {},
            // a variable to store the point where you begin to draw the rectangle
            start = {};
        // a boolean
        var isDrawing = false;

        ctx2.translate(0, TransCanvas.height);
        ctx2.scale(1, -1);

        function handleMouseDown(e) {
            start = oMousePos(TransCanvas, e);
            isDrawing = true;
        }
    
        function handleMouseMove(e) {
            if (isDrawing) {
                m = oMousePos(TransCanvas, e);
                draw();  
            }
        }

        function handleMouseUp(e) {
            isDrawing = false;
            if (boundingBoxes.length < 2) {
                var box = Object.create(annotation);
                box.x = o.x;
                box.y = o.y;
                box.w = o.w;
                box.h = o.h;
                boundingBoxes.push(box);
                draw();
                box.printCoordinates();
            }
        }

        function draw() {
            if (boundingBoxes.length <= 2) {
                o.x = start.x;  // start position of x
                o.y = start.y;  // start position of y
                o.w = m.x - start.x;  // width
                o.h = m.y - start.y;  // height
         
                ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, TransCanvas.width, TransCanvas.height);
                // draw all the rectangles saved in the rectsRy
                boundingBoxes.map(r => { drawRect(r) })
                // draw the actual rectangle
                ctx2.fillRect(x, TransCanvas.height - y, size, size);
                drawRect(o);
            }
        }

        TransCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
        TransCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        TransCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);


        function drawRect(o) {
          
            ctx2.beginPath(o);
            ctx2.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx2.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx2.rect(o.x, o.y, o.w, o.h);
            ctx2.stroke();
        }

        // Function to detect the mouse position
        function oMousePos(TransCanvas, evt) {
            var ClientRect = TransCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
                y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
            }
        }
```

```css
   #TransCanvas {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        #ColorCanvas {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
        #down {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
        }

        body {
            background-color: ivory;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
        <canvas id="ColorCanvas" width="700" height="900" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
        <canvas id="TransCanvas" width="700" height="800"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead using `e.clientY` use `TransCanvas.height - e.clientY`

```
 // Function to detect the mouse position
    function oMousePos(TransCanvas, evt) {
        var ClientRect = TransCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
            y: canvas.height-Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
        }
    }
```

```js
var ColorCanvas = document.getElementById('ColorCanvas');
        var ctx1 = ColorCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var TransCanvas = document.getElementById('TransCanvas');
        var ctx2 = TransCanvas.getContext('2d');
    
        var rect = {},
            drag = false;


        var bg = new Image();
        bg.src = "Jellyfish.jpg";

        bg.onload = function () {
            ctx1.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
        }

        var annotation = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            w: 0,
            h: 0,
            a: this.x,
            printCoordinates: function () {
                console.log(`X: ${this.x}px, Y: ${this.y}px, Width: ${this.w}px, Height: ${this.h}px`);   
            }     
        };


        //the array of all rectangles
        var boundingBoxes = [];
        // the actual rectangle, the one that is being drawn
        var o = {};
        
        // a variable to store the mouse position
        var m = {},
            // a variable to store the point where you begin to draw the rectangle
            start = {};
        // a boolean
        var isDrawing = false;

        ctx2.translate(0, TransCanvas.height);
        ctx2.scale(1, -1);

        function handleMouseDown(e) {
            start = oMousePos(TransCanvas, e);
            isDrawing = true;
        }
    
        function handleMouseMove(e) {
            if (isDrawing) {
                m = oMousePos(TransCanvas, e);
                draw();  
            }
        }

        function handleMouseUp(e) {
            isDrawing = false;
            if (boundingBoxes.length < 2) {
                var box = Object.create(annotation);
                box.x = o.x;
                box.y = o.y;
                box.w = o.w;
                box.h = o.h;
                boundingBoxes.push(box);
                draw();
                box.printCoordinates();
            }
        }

        function draw() {
            if (boundingBoxes.length <= 2) {
                o.x = start.x;  // start position of x
                o.y = start.y;  // start position of y
                o.w = m.x - start.x;  // width
                o.h = m.y - start.y;  // height
         
                ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, TransCanvas.width, TransCanvas.height);
                // draw all the rectangles saved in the rectsRy
                boundingBoxes.map(r => { drawRect(r) })
                // draw the actual rectangle
                ctx2.fillRect(x, TransCanvas.height - y, size, size);
                drawRect(o);
            }
        }

        TransCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
        TransCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        TransCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);


        function drawRect(o) {
          
            ctx2.beginPath(o);
            ctx2.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx2.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx2.rect(o.x, o.y, o.w, o.h);
            ctx2.stroke();
        }

        // Function to detect the mouse position
        function oMousePos(TransCanvas, evt) {
            var ClientRect = TransCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
                y: TransCanvas.height-Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
            }
        }
```

```css
#TransCanvas {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        #ColorCanvas {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
        #down {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
        }

        body {
            background-color: ivory;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
        <canvas id="ColorCanvas" width="700" height="900" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
        <canvas id="TransCanvas" width="700" height="800"></canvas>
    </div>
```